# implementing simple input stream

Tags: c++, iostream

I want to write a simple `istream` object, that would simply transform another `istream`.

I want to only implement `readline` (which would read a line from the original stream, would process it, and return the processed line), and have some generic code that upon `read` would use my read line, cache it, and give the required amount of bytes as output.

Is there any class that would allow me to do that?

For example

```
struct mystream : istreamByReadLine {
  istream& s;
  mystream(istream& _s):s(_s){}
  virtual string getline() {
    string line;
    getline(s,line);
    f(line);
    return line;
  }
}

class istreamByReadLine : istream {
  ... // implementing everything needed to be istream compatible, using my
  ... // getline() virtual method
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at [boost](http://www.boost.org/).[iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html)? It does most of the grunt work for you (possibly not for your exact use case, but for C++ standard library streams in general).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is the way to go?  In similar cases, I've
either defined a class (e.g. `Line`), with a `>>` operator which
did what I wanted, and read that, e.g.:

```
Line line
while ( source >> line ) ...
```

The class itself can be very simple, with just a `std::string`
member, and an `operator std::string() const` function which
returns it.  All of the filtering work would be done in the
`std::istream& operator>>( std::istream&, Line& dest )`
function.  Or I've installed a filtering streambuf in front of the
normal `streambuf` ; Boost iostream has good support for
this.

Comment: I want to give my stream to other functions that receives an `istream`.

Comment: In which case, you have to use an `istream`.  If these other programs should see the filtered data, then you need a filtering streambuf; if they should see the raw data, then the solution with `Line` is better.